# How to count rows of a table grouped by shortdatestring?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

We have an database with an this structure:

```
public partial class ChartData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Function { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public bool IsError { get; set; }
}
```

Now we want to group the entries of this database by `Timestamp.ToShortDateString()` and then count the entries belonging to this date.

So for example we have:

```
2019-06-04 11:54:02,135,someFunction,30,False,
2019-06-04 11:55:03,135,someFunction,230,False,
2019-06-04 11:56:03,150,someFunction,4,True,
2019-06-05 11:54:03,230,someFunction,46,False,
2019-06-05 11:55:03,230,someFunction,46,False,
```

And I want this result:

```
{date: 2019-06-04, rows: 3}
{date: 2019-06-05, rows: 2}

public List <LogFileDTO> GetLogFilesData() 
{
    var items = db.ChartDatas.GroupBy(x = > new {
        x.Timestamp.ToShortDateString
    }).Select(x = > new LogFileDTO {
            date = x.Timestamp.First(),
            rows = x.Count ?
        }).ToList();
}
```

So I do not really know how to group this input by date and then count the rows of each group.

Comment: what type is `date` in `LogFileDTO` ?

Comment: @MongZhu it says `DateTime  Timestamp` there in the class

Comment: You will want to group by the `date` type using `.Date`. then do the conversion to a string with `ToShortDateString()` after if you need a string like for instance `DateTime.Now.Date` would get the date right now.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss no it doesn't say it there really. He didn't post the class `LogFileDTO`. The query code is a collection of uncompileable statements. So I can only assume that OP wants it to be of type `DateTime`, eventhough he tries to group by a `string` . I rather ask it directly in such cases instead of playing mind reading games

Comment: @MongZhu fair enough

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply need to group on the `Date` property of the `TimeStamp` and then project using `Select` on the `Key` of each `IGropuing` and `Count` like below  :

```
var items = db.ChartDatas.GroupBy(x =>  x.Timestamp.Date)  // group only on Date
                       .Select(x => new LogFileDTO 
                                   {
                                     Date = x.Key.ToShortDateString(),
                                     Rows = x.Count()
                                   }).ToList();
```

`Key` will contain only **date part** of `DateTime` object and `Count()` will tell the number of rows for that date in the group.

Hope it helps!