# Filter the object depending on the field's value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm kinda new to javascript. Here I have the following object:

```
obj = {
 0:{id:1, location: loc1, title:title1},
 1:{id:2, location: loc2, title:title2},
 2:{id:3, location: loc1, title:title3},
 3:{id:4, location: loc3, title:title4},
 4:{id:5, location: loc1, title:title5}
}
```

What I need is to filter the object by location depending on its value and create a new object like the following:

```
obj = {
 loc1:{
      0:{id:1, location: loc1, title:title1},
      1:{id:3, location: loc1, title:title3},
      2:{id:5, location: loc1, title:title5}
    },
 loc2:{
      0:{id:2, location: loc2, title:title2}
    }
 loc3:{
      0:{id:4, location: loc3, title:title4}
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the above object?

I tried using `for` and `push` to a new `array` but the location should be dynamic and may change in the future and I want to have one object to manage like above.

```
var theLoc1 = [], theLoc2 = [];

for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  if(response[i].location == 'loc1'){
    theLoc1.push(response[i]);
  }else if(response[i].location == 'loc2'){
    theLoc2.push(response[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: based on what algorithm you're distributing the values ?

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada NO, the location's value is string.

Comment: also note that the location's value is not fixed and could have a new value.

Comment: Check My Answer is 100% what u need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Code is what u really need:

```
obj = [
                 { id: 1, location: 'loc1', title: 'title1' },
                 { id: 2, location: 'loc2', title: 'title2' },
                 { id: 3, location: 'loc1', title: 'title3' },
                 { id: 4, location: 'loc3', title: 'title4' },
                { id: 5, location: 'loc1', title: 'title5' }
            ];
            var locations = {};

            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

                locations[obj[i].location] = [];
            }
            console.log(locations);


            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

                locations[obj[i].location].push(obj[i]);
            }
            console.log(locations);
```

**Update:It Can be done in a single for loop but for simplicity reasons i wrote it like this. **

Comment: Awesome! it worked! Can you add the single loop at the bottom next to your answer?

Comment: the code would be very ugly, although ill do it as soon as im free. Glad that helped u

Comment: This would put an empty array every time you run this code. Meaning if you want something that is able to UPDATE this object as well, and not just create it for the first time, check if the object has that property first and if not- initialize it to new array

Comment: @RomelIndemne If you want I wrote almost the exactly same thing in one loop a few answers down, you can use that as reference :)

Answer (score 1):

```
let obj;
for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  if( !Object.hasOwnProperty(obj, response[i].location)
  { obj[response[i].location] = []; }
  obj[response[i].location].push(response[i]);
}
```

You can dynamically create JS object properties if you just address them. This means:

```
let obj = {};
obj.bark = "how-how";
console.log(obj.bark); // "how-how";
obj[bark2] = "waf-waf"; 
console.log(obj.bark2); // "waf-waf";
```

you can use it to struct your new object with the locations names, so even if someday you get "location999" it'll still work.

I put the `if` that checks if the object laready has that property because you want the property to be an array. If it wasn't you could've just put the value inside like in my example, but im not sure if `push` would work on it so I initialize it to be empty array just in case. You can check it yourself and ommit the `if` if its not needed.

Comment: there is absolutely no need for the if Object.hasOwnProperty 
because the java script works like a hash table

Comment: Object.hasOwnProperty only to tell the difference between prototypes and methods in java script "the stander use"

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada It is necessary if he wants this code to be able to UPDATE the object as well, not just create it. It is the same answer you gave above, but if you don't check and always perform the `locations[obj[i].location] = [];` - you cannot update the object, just create a new one every time.

Comment: Thank @Gibor! I will check your answer tomorrow. :) Don't worry I created a separate variable for the new object.

Comment: @RomelIndemne np. like I said, our answers are almost the exact same aside from 2 loops vs 1 loop, and the `if` statement which is for a situation you want to use `response` to update existing `obj`. If there is no such scenario, omit the `if` and just leave `obj[response[i].location] = []; obj[response[i].location].push(response[i]);` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

My solution using functional programming.

```
const obj = {
  0: { id: 1, location: 'loc1', title: 'title1' },
  1: { id: 2, location: 'loc2', title: 'title2' },
  2: { id: 3, location: 'loc1', title: 'title3' },
  3: { id: 4, location: 'loc3', title: 'title4' },
  4: { id: 5, location: 'loc1', title: 'title5' }
};

const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((newObject, item) => {
  const location = obj[item].location;
  const index = newObject[location] ? Object.keys(newObject[location]).length : 0;
  return {
    ...newObject,
    [location]: {
      ...newObject[location],
      [index]: obj[item]
    }
  };
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to group your items by location you can iterate your array, see whether its location was already grouped and if not, create a new group for it. Afterwards add the item to the corresponding group.

```
var obj = [
    {id: 1, location: "loc1", title: "title1"},
    {id: 2, location: "loc2", title: "title2"},
    {id: 3, location: "loc1", title: "title3"},
    {id: 4, location: "loc3", title: "title4"},
    {id: 5, location: "loc1", title: "title5"}
];

var formattedArray = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (!formattedArray[obj[i].location]) {
        formattedArray[obj[i].location] = new Array();
    }
    formattedArray[obj[i].location].push(obj[i]);
}
console.log(formattedArray);
```

JsFiddle example code:
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/faizankhan775/Lqz73ybo)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following if your loc1, loc2, loc3 are fixed. (That is what I understood after reading your query)

```js
var response = [
{id:1, location: "loc1", title:"title1"},
{id:2, location: "loc2", title:"title2"},
{id:3, location: "loc1", title:"title3"},
{id:4, location: "loc3", title:"title4"},
{id:5, location: "loc1", title:"title5"}
]
  var resObj = {
published:[],
private: [],
pending:[]
}

for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  if(response[i].location == 'loc1'){
    resObj.published.push(response[i]);
  }else if(response[i].location == 'loc2'){
    resObj.private.push(response[i]);
  }else {
  resObj.pending.push(response[i]);
  }
}
  console.log(resObj)
```

Comment: actually the location's value is not fixed. and could have a new value.

Comment: Cool you can go with @ibrahim-m-nada snippet. Just club the loop for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
locations[obj[i].location] = [];
locations[obj[i].location].push(obj[i]);
}

Answer (score -1):

I think the better way to do this, is to group your objects already in your backend. You can use the linq function `.GroupBy(x => x.location)`.

This is near the same problem:
[How to count rows of a table grouped by shortdatestring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57252628/how-to-count-rows-of-a-table-grouped-by-shortdatestring)

Comment: This does not answer the question. Why are you assuming that the backend is C#?

Answer (score -1):

```
// create an array of arrays;
var groupOfLocations[];

// loop on your locations
for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    // push if already existing
    for(var iGroup = 0; iGroup < groupOfLocations.length; iGroup++) {
        if(groupOfLocations[iGroup][0].location == response[i].location) {
           groupOfLocations[iGroup].push(response[i]); break; 
    }
    // create a new array if not found
    if(iGroup >= groupOfLocations.length) groupOfLocations.push(new array(response[i])); 
}
```

May contains syntax mistakes, but the idea is here.